# Cases where having nulls are useful

Tags: null

There's a real drive to eliminate null from programming and there are lots of examples of null being bad in languages. What are good uses of null and some of its benefits to programming.

Comment: You only want the up sides? That seems like a sterile exercise to me.

Comment: is this somehow related to "cases where the number '0' is useful?"

Comment: "good use" is a contradiction. The meaning of null is unused/unassigned. So then figuring out whether it's good or bad is premature. It's simply unused. Handle it!

Answer (score 1):

In all computer languages that support `null`, it means "unknown" (or "unassigned" - similar). It can be useful to distinguish "unknown" from a specific value. This is especially of use where all possible values of the type variable are possible value of its meaning. If the meaning range of a variable is limited, a value outside this range can be reserved for "unknown".

eg in java:

```
int age = -1; // people can't have a negative age, so safe to use -1 as unknown
Integer hashCode = null; // hash can be any integer, so need to use null
```

The downside of allowing null is in many languages you need to handle that:

again in java:

```
boolean hasSameHash = hashCode != null && hashCode.equals(other.hashCode);
```

Answer (score 1):

Having a null is like having an unused variable. Sure it's great to have it, but it's not very useful. You could assign a value but then it wouldn't be unused. Having a null is not a bad thing if you handle it. So it's not really bad, but it's not useful.

When is it a good thing? Well I suppose the knowledge that the value hasn't been set is useful and thus good.

Some people use null to represent another value. e.g. null means something different from a zero or non-zero number. Personally I avoid assigning null when possible. For me the only meaning of null is unused/unassigned. It doesn't have any further cosmic purpose and therefore cannot be good/bad. Only useful/nonuseful. Or if unhandled it might cause an error and of course errors are bad if unanticipated.

It seems to me that the real question here is why do we have nulls at all. But it's a little like asking why do you have an empty basket. You have to fill it to be useful. But you can't fill it until you make (or get) the basket first. So I guess we're just gonna have nulls... until we assign a value. Gotta deal with it.

You can avoid nulls by assigning a default value. That's great for strings or numbers although sometimes you may want to know whether the value has been actively set or not.